# Styling HTML5 number input

Tags: css, html, input, styles, numbers

Is it possible to style the default HTML5 `input type="number"` to look something like this:[image]

Or do I have to use additional elements for the 'arrows'? Couldn't find the CSS selectors for them.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvcjvgjz/)

HTML:

```
<input class="qnt amount" name="qnt" min="1" max="100" type="number" value="1">
```

CSS:

```
input{
    display:block;
    margin-top:12px;
    text-align:center;
    width:125px;
    height:30px;
    outline:1px solid black;
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: They are browser specific things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Form fields are drawn by the underliyng chrome (meaning browser/OS combination). They don't have CSS selectors.

If you like to have your style. you have to make some new element in front of the original input (or hide the input and put that new element in place). This element will work in some way with JavaScript and always updates the value of the input field.

Comment: I thought since you could select input[type=number] and play around with the css, maybe the 'arrows' were reachable too.. oh well :) Thank You

Comment: But I found some workaround here: http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/WwfW9/ Maybe it's browser compatible

Comment: Haha, now thats something... is there some way to show the 'spin buttons' all the time though?