# Styling <input type=number/> spinner arrows the right way

Tags: html, css, forms

The arrows of `<input type="number"/>` in Mac are extremely small and not useful both on Chrome and Firefox even on Safari.

[image]

What is the right way to style them without adding extra arrow images and etc. Note that I've already seen these thread and it didn't solve the issue:
[Styling a input type=number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024771/styling-a-input-type-number)

the out comes for that thread on MacOS are these:

[image: LcSalazar]
[image]

Comment: I suggest finding a form reset css that normalizes the elements across all the browsers because working with their native styling can be frustrating and trying to figure out how to reset them back to no styling can be difficult.

Comment: This question has been asked many, many times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273377/style-input-type-number, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478463/change-the-appearance-of-input-type-number, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266888/styling-html5-number-input-spin-box-in-chrome, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159135/styling-html5-number-input

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan even though these questions are similar to each other but the solutions don't seem to be smart and many of them just ignoring the main issue even many of them don't solve the issue at all because they just test their results on their own platform. That's way I asked it to find the right way.

Comment: Please read those answers. You'll find there is no way of styling the spinners in a completely cross-browser manner. Stack Overflow is for creating a library of high-quality questions and answers, not to have the same question asked over and over again in the hopes that an answer will come.

Comment: You did not get my purpose yet! I don't want to have a same look on every platform but to adjust the current look in Mac. Which is not mentioned in anywhere before. Please read the question carefully and answer it if you have the knowledge else don't try to teach me what I already know

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I found the way to make the native arrows a little bit bigger. Here is the trick:

```css
input[type=number] {
  line-height: 30px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />
```

It worked well both on Chrome and Safari

Comment: This works also very nicely on Chrome for Windows. In Firefox for Windows it just displays it as without any styling.

Comment: Firefox for Mac as well